# ColorPicker validation and required not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

At first I tried with just the 'required' attribute, but as it never seems to be checked, I added an extremely simple validator which checks the length of the 'color' property... but nothing seems to work. In the same form I have other inputText required components which are correctly checked when I press the commandButton.

I have the following code:

```
<p:colorPicker id="color" value="#{backBean.color}" required="true"  requiredMessage="Required!" validator="ColorValidator" validatorMessage="Required!"/>

<p:commandButton id="createOrUpdateButton"
                 actionListener="{backBean.createOrUpdate}"
                 process="@form"
                 update="@all"
                 value="Save"
                 style="width: 95%;" />
```

Validator:

```
@FacesValidator("ColorValidator")
public class ColorValidator implements Validator{

public ColorValidator(){

}
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (value==null || value.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
      FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Color validation failed.","Please select a color.");
      msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
      throw new ValidatorException(msg);
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Did you add a `<p:messages for="color"/>`?

Comment: @Selaron it tried with that but no luck.

Comment: Then I fear we need a very [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: It was simply not supported!

[Issue #5887](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5887) and [issue #5892](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5892)  addressing this and offer fixes which should be included in PrimeFaces version 9.0.

Comment: thanks, looking forward for it to be included soon.